# soql on events, to display all the events regardless of who is assigned to in a VF page within a community

Tags: soql, community, administration, event, field-level-security

I am not sure if I am approaching my problem the right way, maybe not, so I will give a very brief explanation of what I am trying to achieve:

Currently I have 2 communities, Community 1 is focused on making calls and it has 2 sort of users internal and external. The external users will make an specific type of calls and the second type of users will follow up this calls. After the external users made the call I am creating an event, that looks something like:

Assigned to:  Person who made the call (external user)

What.Id: Opportunity

custom field: an specific value

The internal user, should be able to see a list of all activities made by all the external users, so I am trying to do something like:

```
SELECT Subject, Id, What.Id, Custom_Field__c FROM Event WHERE Custom_Field__c = 'an specific value'
```

However this only displays if the event is assign to the current log in user. I need to be able to display all the events, regardless of who is assigned to it.

On community 2, is more for sales people who eventually will need to see the list of all this events created

So I am not really sure what I am missing, the class the I am using is set like:

public without sharing

**EDIT:**

THe following are the options that I have from  Sharing Settings in setup, I dont have that option. My Salesforce is the enterprice, and this image was taking from admin user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your security. Go to the permission of activity and make it visible for all profiles. this may solve the issue.

You can Check this link for more information

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm

Comment: hi, Thank you for the prompt reply, could you please specify more where is (Go to the permission of activity).  Is this the same as Sharing Settings in setup? untick the activities checkbox?

Comment: yeah in that go to activities, and edit those setting. you can select controlled by parent, you can see all the events of users under you.  
To view all the events you must have a "View all data" Permission. If you are a system administrator then you can assign that permission to your profile and you can access all the data.

Comment: Hi I have modify the options but it doesnt seem to do anything, please see the image above in case I am in the wrong place. Thanks

Comment: Also it works fine on full salesforce license, but as i said on my question is a community

Comment: Lets see, wait for other answers.